# MWAA load custom file info to DAG

Tags: mwaa

I'm trying to use a file in a DAG.
The codes I want to use is basically this:

```html
conf_device_info = OmegaConf.load(f"./config/{dag_name}/config_dtype.json")
```

and my bucket is currently like this:

```html
my-bucket
--/ dags
    -- /config
           --/{dag_name}
                      --/config_dtype.json
    -- dag_with_the_code.py
    -- /utils
           --s3_manager.py
```

When I import s3_manager with "import utils.s3_manager" , it goes fine.
When I try to run the code the OmegaConf code, it says

```html
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/airflow/config/{dag_name}/config_dtype.json'
```

What should I do to do what I'm trying to acheive?
Why is import working and referencing file with absolute path not working..?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the airflow documentation there is a section about [relative imports](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/modules_management.html#don-t-use-relative-imports)

When I'm importing config files, I usually use something like

```
from pathlib import Path
CONFIG_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / "include" / "config.yaml"

with open(CONFIG_PATH, encoding="UTF-8") as config_file:
    config = yaml.safe_load(config_file)
```

Or you can use airflow environment variables for the location of the DagBag

Comment: tried other way around, but this method looks really helpful. thanks.